# WorkItem-only view in TFS-2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-web-access, tfs-2010

In our company, Project Managers want to keep track of all Requirements in TFS using Web portal. I heard about a limited version of Web Access (Work Item Only View). Can this be done using it?

Comment: Do they want to add/edit the workitems without using TFS CAL license?

Comment: yes will they be able to edit all the workitems in their projects using Work Item Only View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In work item Only View, you can create new Requirements or view and update existing Requirements which you have created. As part of projects, If you want to modify the Requirements that are neither created by you nor assigned to you. Then, you have to use Team System Web Access and will need CAL.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of options, guys I work with have installed a package called urban turtle http://urbanturtle.com/ which integrates with the web portal, and provides a virtual Kanban board, where you can view just the work items and slide them back and forth.

You can also link Excel 2010 to your work items (there's a button in VS 2010), and filter them in that. Provides a nice overview of everything in one place, and a much simpler mechanism of marking a work item as done, however it did break a couple of times, so might not be the most reliable of mechanisms.

Comment: It looks like urbanturtle is for scrum template users but we are using MSF CMMI process template.

Comment: You can use Urban Turtle with any of the process templates.

Answer (score 2):

I think "[Urban turtle](http://urbanturtle.com)" or "[Eylean board](http://www.eylean.com)" is what you are looking for.